# Trying to paste a typed command to a terminal

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, xdotool

I am very new to robotics and ROS and am looking for some help trying to create some keyboard shortcuts that allow me to paste them into a terminal.

Currently i am using the xdotool to do this. I am able to create a new shortcut and have the xdotool print to the terminal if i do something simple like ( ex. 'Hello world' or 'test' ) The text i need to have printed to the terminal has several differant symbols and characters, i dont know if this is why i am having an issue.

The typed text i need to printed is:

```
rosservice call /xm540arm/torque_enable "{cmd_type: 'group', name: 'arm', enable: false}"
```

when creating a new shortcut this is what i have put in the command section:

```
/bin/bash -c "sleep 0.5 && xdotool type 'rosservice call /xm540arm/torque_enable "{cmd_type: 'group', name: 'arm', enable: false}"'
```

I am not sure if the way i am doing this is correct or not, i am open to any suggestions or other options to accomplish this task.

any help would be greatly appreciated

thanks
Mike

Comment: im sorry i guess i left out that information. i am running ubuntu 20.04 and have mate for the desktop. using a raspberry pi4 as the computer

Comment: I was able to get the message to print to the terminal. it is not printing it exactly the same as i have it type to print. When i run the command that got printed to the terminal this is the return message i get.                                                                                                                               rosservice call /xm540arm/torque_enable {cmd_type:group,name:arm,enable:false}
ERROR: Unable to send request. One of the fields has an incorrect type:
  field enable is not a bool

srv file:
string cmd_type
string name
bool enable
---

Comment: Additional info needs to be added to the question via edit not as comments.

Comment: Are you sure this is really what you want? I suspect you are actually looking for shell aliases and not a way to paste commands. Can you explain what the final objective is? Do you want to run the commands or just see them?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a double-quoted string, you need to escape any internal double quotes so that they are not read as ending the quoted string:

```
/bin/bash -c "sleep 0.5 && xdotool type 'rosservice call /xm540arm/torque_enable \"{cmd_type: 'group', name: 'arm', enable: false}\"'"
```

Comment: terdon thank you for the reply, i will try that and let you know how it works out. What i am trying to accomplish is to have the command run to turn the torque off to the robot arms motors. then i can pose the arm and torque the motor back on without having to copy and paste each time i need a new pose. I am open to your comment about shell aliases. All of this is still new to me so i will have to do some research about them to learn what they are and how to use them. thanks again